# Update "Log.i" in TextView with ScrollBar

Tags: android, textview, logging, settext

I have in my layout.xml a TextView with "id = txtLog".

Where do the test results from my application using:

```
Log.i("Result:", "Value of x = " + x);
```

for show result in LogCat.

It is possible to show these results "Log.i" within the TextView?

Note: I left a space at the bottom of my application to show the TextView.
Like a console.

**I would like to display these messages on TextView.
If possible create a scroll bar and display every time I use Log.i**

I am a beginner, do not know if it is possible. Yet thanks.

Comment: post your code where u are using Log.i

Comment: Your question has a lot of grammatical mistakes. I don't fully grasp what your problem is. Can you please fix your grammar?

Comment: Sorry, is that I am Brazilian. I do not speak very well. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I would think

```
myTextView.setText(myTextView.getText() + "Value of x = " + x + "\n");
```

would work.

EDIT:

Also, to make the `TextView` scrollable, you need to set a movement method like so:

```
myTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

EDIT 2:

If you want the information to go to both `Log.i` and a `TextView`, then you need a method that holds a reference to the `TextView` you want to update.

```
public static void LogToView(TextView myTextView, String title, String message) {
   Log.i(title, message);
   myTextView.setText(myTextView.getText() + title + ":  Value of x = " + x + "\n");
}
```

Put that in whatever class or in your Activity class.  Use it instead of `Log.i` and the message will be passed to both.

Comment: Not worked as I wanted.
I wanted a method that automatically always added the text in the TextView Log.i but the bottom line.